# Send Email without user's Authenication

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

That is what I want

I want to develop a feedback form. So I create a sample activity for sending email from on mail address to another. But I want that mail sends without authentication. or if it is not possible then change the from email address to another email address. there is my code.

This is my Mail.java Class

```
    public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;

private String[] _to;
private String _from;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;


public Mail() {
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    _user = ""; // username
    _pass = ""; // password
    _from = ""; // email sent from
    _subject = ""; // email subject
    _body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
    // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}


public Mail(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    _user = user;
    _pass = pass;
}

 public void setTo(String[] toArr){
     _to = toArr;
 }

 public void setFrom(String from){
     _from = from;
 }
 public void setSubject(String subject){
     _subject = subject;
 }

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
            && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
            && !_body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}



@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if (_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if (_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
} }
```

This is my Send Email Class

```
public class SendEmail extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Mail m = new Mail("<USER EMAIL>", "<PASSWORD>"); 
    String[] toArr = {"<EMAIL-1>", "<EMAIL-2>"}; 
    m.setTo(toArr); 
    m.setFrom("<EMAIL>"); 
    m.setSubject("This is aSubject."); 
    m.setBody("This is my Email body"); 
    try { 

      if(m.send()) { 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email was sent successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      } else { 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      } 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
    } 
}


       }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Whether authentication is required or not is up to your mail server.  Most mail servers require authentication as a way of preventing spam.

Answer (score 0):

Most SMTP servers accept e-mail messages without authorization only from their own network (e.g. company network). When you need to use 3rd party SMTP server, it will require authorization.